# How can I install a Hebrew supporting Microsoft Word?

Tags: virtualization, microsoft-office, hebrew

I've installed Ubuntu for my little sister's PC, it fits perfectly with most of the things she does except for word processing.

She *must* use MS office (and not LibreOffice as it is not 100% compatible with MS Office) for school projects. I've tried installing it with Wine and PlayOnLinux, but that causes problems with Hebrew, it just doesn't write correctly. Now I'm pursuing other alternatives.

I'm thinking of trying installing a VM on on her computer and using it for all the must have Windows applications. How's that solution? Are there any better alternatives?

Comment: Yes, there is a better alternative.  Post the question to a MS Office site, since it has nothing to do with Ubuntu at all.

Comment: Why do you say that LibreOffice as it is not 100% compatible with MS Office?

Comment: Ziv, is your intent to ask about running MS Word under Windows on a virtual machine running under Ubuntu? I think that's what I'm reading, but it isn't clear from the question, particularly the title. Can you make your question more direct? If I understand your intent I think it's a good question.

Comment: Sometimes, there is no way around Windows software, especially in countries or institutions that depend on MS heavily. I think a VM would be a good solution, if the computer can handle it.

Comment: This question appears to be abandoned and unanswered, could you perhaps add more detail to your question? If this question no longer applies then you can either delete it or answer it yourself if you've solved the problem. Thanks!